# Estilizando componentes no React

Tags: javascript, css, aplicação-web, react

Estou iniciando meus estudos/desenvolvimento com React porém estou com um problema na estilização dos componentes. Mesmo importando o arquivo CSS no no meu componente,o estilo não está pegando. Como posso resolver isso??

```js
import React from 'react';

import './styles.css';

const Header = () => (
  <header id="main-header">JShunt</header>

);

export default Header;
```

```js
import React from  'react';

import './styles.css';

import Header from './components/Header';


const App = () => (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <p>Bricando com React</p>
    </div>
);

export default App;
```

```css
header #main-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #da552f;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: como o Carlos colocou como resposta, verifica se o arquivo styles.css está na sua pasta components/Header

Vendo o seu código dá para supor que existem dois arquivos styles.css, uma na mesma pasta do App e outra na pasta do Header

Comment: Editei a pergunta colocando a screenshot do diretório. Sim,são dois estilos: um do componenente e o outro é global

Comment: Altere a declaração da sua classe para `header#main-header {` e [voila](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6u7nzr?), se quiser, pode até manter somente `#main-header`

Comment: @MarceloBoni. Perfeito!! Tinha tentado desse jeito e não foi aí agora sim. De qualquer maneira,grato! Estilo aplicado

Answer (score 0):

mostra o seu diretorio, o css do Header ta no mesmo diretorio do componente Header?

falta colocar tbm o return, deixei o exemplo correto

```
import React from 'react';

import './styles.css';

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header id="main-header">JShunt</header>
  )
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Cara, quando você omite as chaves em uma arrow function, você já está retornando a expressão. Não precisa de return no caso do Eric. Dá uma olhada no https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Editei a pergunta com uma screenshot do diretório.